# How can .htaccess change $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a website at `http://ex.com/web2/` this is a real path in my server, but I wanted visitors to be able to access the website also over the URL `http://ex.com/web3/` (without changing the URL on the browser), so after looking around (and asking help) I added the following to my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^web3/?$ /web2/ [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^web3/(.+)$ /web2/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

The "silent" redirect that DOES NOT change the browser URL works fine, but in PHP if I `print $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` I get the URL the user placed on the browser, `/web3/` instead of `/web2/`.

Is there any way `.htaccess` can also "fake" the path that is sent to the PHP var? 
(I was told this would be hard or even impossible.)

Thank you.

Comment: You typically also get `REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI` as well, alternatively can populate one with `[E=ORG_URL:$1]`

Comment: Adding `[E=ORG_URL:$1]` does not change the value at `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`.

Comment: Use the redirect or modrewrite commands within. Htaccess

Comment: Of course $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] doesn’t change, because that value is _supposed_ to contain what the client requested. What for do you need it to contain `/web2/` in your script anyway, and why can’t you change anything in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have mod_proxy loaded, you could internally proxy the request. That will change the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, but it's sort of a round about way to do it. Would be far more efficient if it all happened in the php scripts.

```
RewriteRule ^web3/?$ /web2/ [L,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^web3/(.+)$ /web2/$1 [L,NC,P]
```

Just need to add the `P` flag to the square brackets.

Comment: Sorry, But I try to use your recommendation...To use this only I need to uncomment...

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so #this line?